# I am getting 404 error when trying to connect telegram bot with ngrok

Tags: python, telegram-bot, ngrok

I am trying to connect my telegram bot with ngrok but when I am trying to do that, I am facing with that error.

{
"ok": false,
"error_code": 404,
"description": "Not Found"
}

The step that I want to complete is:
[image]

Here is the link for that page: https://www.pragnakalp.com/create-telegram-bot-using-python-tutorial-with-examples/

Comment: What happens when you go to http://localhost:5000?